# Grid Reference Image style and Button style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reference, styles

I currently have a couple buttons in a grid that have the same xaml image style and button style. I am trying to make a grid reference to call from the style feature of the button. I can do the button style work but I am having issues coding the image style so that it is one call (new to xaml). Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="edit_32.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch"
                    Value="Uniform" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                            Value="save_smallest.png" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch"
                            Value="Uniform" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>

<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanEdit}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer to my question. This set of code allows me to use dual style setting while creating only one call for the button's style:

```
<!--SaveEditImageSwitch-->
<Image x:Key="SaveEditImage" x:Shared="False">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="edit_32.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch"
                    Value="Uniform" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                            Value="save_smallest.png" />
                    <Setter Property="Stretch"
                            Value="Uniform" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>

<!--ButtonEditSaveStyle-->
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="ButtonEditSaveStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Content"
            Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=SaveEditImage}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanEdit}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button Width="32"
        Height="22"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord"
        Click="gdEmployeeInfo_btnUpdateRecord_Click" 
        Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ButtonEditSaveStyle}">
```